# nodejs async await not returning array

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am able to console.log the output properly, but when I try to return the array, it fails (ie: no output)

```
    //get all geo route
    app.get('/api/geo', function(req, res){
       res.send(getGeo());
    });

    async function getGeo() {
      let query = firestore.collection('geo'); //.where('foo', '==', 'bar');

      let response = await query.listDocuments().then(documentRefs => {
        return firestore.getAll(...documentRefs);
      }).then(documentSnapshots => {
         let geomatches = [];
         for (let documentSnapshot of documentSnapshots) {
            if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
              //console.log(`Found document with data: ${documentSnapshot.id}`);
              geomatches[documentSnapshot.id] = documentSnapshot.data();
            }//if
         }//for
         return geomatches;
      });

      return response;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getGeo()` is an `async` function. You should use `await` to call it. Also declare your route callback as `async`:

```
//get all geo route
app.get('/api/geo', async function(req, res){
   res.send(await getGeo());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use await

```
  //get all geo route
   app.get('/api/geo', async function(req, res){
      res.send( await getGeo());
   });
```